# Mailgun is sending emails as "unknown"?

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I am using Mailgun with laravel to send mail. This is what the headers show in the email that arrives by me:

```
Received: from <unknown> (<unknown> []) by api-n01.prod.eu-central-1.postgun.com with HTTP id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Mon, 28 Feb 2022 02:08:33 GMT
```

And a little lower down, I do see correct details:

```
From: "My Name" <noreply@mysite.com>
```

Why would received be showing unknown? Should I be specifying something somewhere explicitly? I am not using any fancy implementation, it's standard Mailgun.

The reason I need this fixed is because certain mailboxes block this email because of that unknown bit.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

My mail settings are pretty standard. In mail/config.php I have:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

But this part works. It's this part that makes no sense:

```
 Received: from <unknown> (<unknown> [])
```

It's almost like mail/config.php also needs a "received" entry, just like it has a "from" entry? But that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the from part? Normally you'd do it with the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`/`MAIL_FROM_NAME` environment variable that is used inside `config/mail.php` - is this what you're doing?

The reason I suggest this is because normally I'd expect the name/email combination to be formatted like `"My Name" <noreply@mysite.com>` (note the triangular brackets around the email). I wonder if that is what is tripping up Mailgun.

Comment: I have all of those correctly configured and I can see that because this part is correct: From: "My Name" <noreply@mysite.com>. I opened a mailgun ticket so long to  try and figure it out.